# New to C#. Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. nJupiter LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap

HELP......Just moved to C# from vb and Im really lost with this.

```
var ldapmembershipUser = (LdapMembershipUser)System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser("username");
var cnAttributeValues = ldapmembershipUser.Attributes["cn"];
```

Code bails at cnAttributeValues with Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I dont know how to set it as a new ??  Object?

This is in reference to the nJupiter google controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Membership.GetUser(string)` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx) to return:

> A MembershipUser object representing the specified user. If the username parameter does not correspond to an existing user, this method returns Nothing.

So that's what's happening here - `ldapmembershipUser` is null because there's no such user. You should check for that and act accordingly:

```
// Note name casing change here to keep my sanity.
if (ldapMembershipUser == null)
{
    // Take appropriate action
}
```

Note that you could also have problems if `GetUser` returns a reference to an object which *isn't* an `LdapMembershipUser`.

Comment: Oh !@#$@#$.. LOL. I want to shoot myself in the foot for this..Your sooo correct and i was so blind not to see it. ("username") as a string needs to have the value set from another variable..

Answer (score 1):

That would mean that `GetUser` returned `null`, probably because there is no user with that name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the user exists first before trying to get the attributes.